# PL/SQL getting binary_float data from a file

Tags: plsql, binary-data, file-read

I have a file on a Unix box that I need to read into my PL/SQL procedure. The file is 2904 bytes of data which it transpires is a contiguous string of 726 numbers of 4 bytes, so probably BINARY_FLOAT format, no line returns or new lines etc. 
I am struggling come up with the best way to read this data into my procedure, I eventually want to split it into 6 tables/collections each of 121 numbers. Any views or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Go for external tables..Google down you will find many solutions

Answer (score 0):

Use utl_file library, with it you can do many operations on files.

Comment: Sorry, probably didn't express myself well enough, I am aware of and use both external tables and utl_file, however in both cases I've only ever used with character inputs and delimited lines. I'm unable to get either option to work with the input file that I have to use.